# Simplest AppDomain and FileNotFound exception

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I wrote a simple lines of creating separate AppDomain, but getting strange exception of FileNotFound : Could not load file or assembly... Considering necessary parameters are filled , this issue is very confusing to me:

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
Evidence evidence = new Evidence(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence);
evidence.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
evidence.AddHost(new Zone(SecurityZone.MyComputer));
AppDomain hostedAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Demo", evidence, setup);                   
hostedAppDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(hostedAppDomain_AssemblyResolve);   **// Exception in this line**
```

Comment: in ASp.net ot WinForm .? then Which Assemlby is missing .?

Comment: Simple c# dll. Try to imagine - missing dll is which is declared in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.

Comment: Can u Please tell me on which line is Error is coming./

Comment: Last line. Attentively look at the code and do not ask silly questions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out.. need to change

```
setup.ApplicationBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

to

```
setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```